# Grayscale Bootstrap Navbar - change color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working with this bootstrap theme: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/ and I'm trying to change the color of the navbar. I hate CSS so I'm completely clueless on this matter. Can anyone tell me which line I am meant to modify to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make change sin default bootstrap class make a class .navbar-default and override the with what ever color you want

```
.navbar-default{
       background-color:#000000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

139 line in your grayscale.css

```
    background: #000;
```

http://www.color-hex.com/ here you can find all the hex codes for colors.